# Error when trying install Ruby with RVM on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, ruby, rvm

I installed RVM in my Ubuntu 17.10 but when I try to install Ruby I have this error:

```
$ rvm install 2.5.0
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/17.10/x86_64/ruby-2.5.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more    information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating systemjacques password required for 'apt-get --quiet --yes update': .-|
...
Installing required packages: libreadline6-dev....
Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install libreadline6-dev',
please read /home/jacques/.rvm/log/1514981551_ruby-2.5.0/package_install_libreadline6-dev.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

If I try to install libreadline6-dev with `apt-get` I receive this error:

```
The following packages have mismatched dependencies:
  libreadline6-dev: Depends: libreadline6 (= 6.2-9ubuntu1) but 6.3-8ubuntu8 is to be installed
```

Comment: do you have 6.2 installed? is it available in the repo?

Comment: Did you update your system before executing that command?, I just followed the instructions here: [RVM Package for Ubuntu - Install](https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm) and then executed `rvm install 2.5.0` and it works perfectly.

Comment: galoget is your version of Ubuntu 17.10? Because I followed the instructions but I can not install any version of Ruby. Always give error when I try to install.

Comment: What's the content of `/home/jacques/.rvm/log/1514981551_ruby-2.5.0/package_install_libreadline6-dev.log` and the output of `apt-cache policy libreadline6 libreadline6-dev`?

Comment: The same error I said before: The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have mismatched dependencies:
  libreadline6-dev: Depends: libreadline6 (= 6.2-9ubuntu1) but 6.3-8ubuntu8 is to be installed
E: Impossible to fix problems, you kept (hold) broken packages.

Comment: Yes @JacquesMarques, I have Ubuntu 17.10, try the commands in my answer and tell us if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved that issue in Ubuntu 17.10:

First, install the required dependencies one by one, this can be done by executing:

`sudo apt install libreadline6`

`sudo apt install libreadline6-dev`

`sudo apt install libgmp-dev`

`sudo apt install software-properties-common`

Then proceed with the normal installation instructions:

`sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/rvm`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install rvm`

`source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh`

`rvm install 2.5.0`

If you want, I can share screenshots of the process that I followed, step by step.

Hope it helps.